# Linker Error with templated class

Tags: c++, templates, lnk2005

I'm getting linker errors when trying to compile a templated class.  I'm not too hot on C++ templated programming and the workings of the compiler (MSBuild/VS2012) and am having difficulty in determining what I've done wrong.  I'm compiling with /CLR and I get a series of linker errors (LNK2005) when I try to compile my source files, which approximate to:

ISaveStrategy.h:

```
#pragma once
#pragma unmanaged

template<class T>
class ISaveStrategy
{
public:
    enum SaveResult {OK, Error}; 

    virtual SaveResult Save(const T&  itemToSave) = 0;
};
```

SaveToXmlStrategy.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <gcroot.h>
#include "ISaveStrategy.h"

#pragma unmanaged

namespace System{namespace Xml{ref class XmlWriter;}}

template<class T>
class SaveToXmlStrategy : public ISaveStrategy<T>
{
public:

    SaveToXmlStrategy(gcroot<System::Xml::XmlWriter^> writer)
        : m_writer(writer)
    {}

    virtual SaveResult Save(const T& itemToSave);

private:
    gcroot<System::Xml::XmlWriter^> m_writer;
};
```

SaveToXmlStrategy.cpp:

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SaveToXmlStrategy.h"
#include "IKeyFrame.h"
#include "IKeyFrameTransition.h"
#include "ICueProvider.h"

#pragma managed

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;

template class SaveToXmlStrategy<IKeyFrameTransition>;
SaveToXmlStrategy<IKeyFrameTransition>::SaveResult SaveToXmlStrategy<IKeyFrameTransition>::Save(const IKeyFrameTransition& keyFrame)
{
    return SaveResult::OK;
}


template class SaveToXmlStrategy<ICueProvider>;
SaveToXmlStrategy<ICueProvider>::SaveResult SaveToXmlStrategy<ICueProvider>::Save(const ICueProvider& keyFrame)
{
    return SaveResult::OK;
}


template class SaveToXmlStrategy<IKeyFrame>;
SaveToXmlStrategy<IKeyFrame>::SaveResult SaveToXmlStrategy<IKeyFrame>::Save(const IKeyFrame& keyFrame)
{
    SaveResult result = SaveResult::OK;
    return result;
}
```

Implementation.cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "SaveToXmlStrategy.cpp"

//inside a function body :
ISaveStrategy<IKeyFrame>& keyFrameSaver = SaveToXmlStrategy<IKeyFrame>(xmlWriter.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

Gaar!  The problem was that in the implementation file I was including the SaveToXmlStrategy.cpp file, not the .h - it wasn't until I re-read my question on here that I realised the problem was staring me in the face!